# React Vscode snippets does not work on macbook m1 how can i fix it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, vscode-extensions, vscode-snippets

react snippets does not work on my macbook air M1 what is the reason? or how can i fix it?
expo snippets does not work also but it tried on windows and it works

i tried reinstalling the vs code and the snippet extensions.

Comment: Hello. Did it use to work previously on your MAC? Another question: can you please share with us what is the code snippet that you're working on and what you are expecting from React snippets to give you? Thanks

Comment: Hi, there are the snippets, this is my first Mac, previously i was using Windows

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=burkeholland.simple-react-snippets

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets

Comment: I mean, in what exactly React snippets is not working in your case? Which feature is not behaving as intended? We need to know in order to reproduce it on our end

Comment: for example import {tabs} https://prnt.sc/snD96RgVoRKF
import React
https://prnt.sc/dS7_qJSWbDmk  
etc. many of them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.